# How does Scylla handles agressive memflush & compaction on write work load?

Tags: latency, scylla

How does Scylla guarantee/keeps write latency low for write workload case, as more write would produce more memflush and compaction? Is there a throttling to it? Would be really helpful if someone can asnwer.

Answer (score 5):

In essence, Scylla provides consistent low latency by parallelizing the problem, and then properly prioritizing user-facing vs. back-office tasks.

**Parallelizing** - Scylla uses a shard-per-thread architecture. Each thread is responsible for *all activities* for its token range. Reads, writes, compactions, repairs, etc.

**Prioritizing** - Each thread is scheduled according to the priorities of the tasks. High priority tasks like dealing with read (query) and write (commitlog) receive the highest priority. Back-office tasks such as memtable flushes, compaction and repair are only done when there are spare cycles. Which - given the nanosecond scale of modern CPUs - there usually are.

If there are not enough spare cycles, and RAM or Disk start to fill, Scylla will bump the priority of the back-office tasks in order to save the node. So that will, in fact, inject some latency. But that is an indication that you are probably undersized, and should add some resources.

I would recommend starting with the Scylla Architecture whitepaper at https://go.scylladb.com/real-time-big-data-database-principles-offer.html. There are also many in-depth talks from Scylla developers at https://www.scylladb.com/resources/tech-talks/

For example, https://www.scylladb.com/2020/03/26/avi-kivity-at-core-c-2019/ talks at great depth about shard-per-core.

https://www.scylladb.com/tech-talk/oltp-or-analytics-why-not-both/ talks at great depth about task prioritization.

Comment: not much I can say, thanks a lot. This came up while testing my DB (not competing tough :), just for learning I created one) where compaction & memflush took priority and write latency got effected. I will definitely learn more about this and improve it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Memtable flush is more urgent than regular compaction as we on one hand want to flush late, in order to create fewer sstables in level 0 and on the other, we like to evacuate memory from ram. We have a memory controller which automatically determine the flush condition. It is done in the background while operations for to the commitlog and get flushed according to the configured criteria.

Compaction is more of a background operation and we have controllers for it too. Go ahead and search the blog for compaction

Comment: You should trust Dor's answer above mine. He's the CEO and co-founder of ScyllaDB, so has a much deeper understanding of the controller and scheduler internals. Thanks for chiming in, Dor!

Comment: really grateful for your time @dor.